# Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I use 
hibernate 3 , spring version: 3.0.0.RC3 and I use postgreSql 9.3

I used c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar and postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar

I have a connection loss problem.

this is the error :

```
 [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8010-126) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
[org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8010-127) An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.

...............
...............
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:527)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 155 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@3247c372 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
```

this my config in applicationContext-db.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
         <bean id="dataSource" class = "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
       <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>

        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"/> 

        <property name="user" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
           <!-- pool sizing -->
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />

        <!-- retries -->
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="30" />
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" /> <!-- 1s -->
        <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false" />

        <!-- refreshing connections -->
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="180" /> <!-- 3min -->
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="10" /> <!-- 1h -->

        <!-- timeouts and testing -->
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="30000" /> <!-- 30s -->
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60" /> <!-- 60 -->
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" /> 

    </bean>
</beans>
```

also I have this configation in **postgresql.conf**

```
max_connections = 1500
shared_buffers = 8GB
```

this is my performence of **Database server**

```
8 cpu
24 GB memory
```

also this is my performence of **Application server**

```
8 cpu
24 GB memory
```

I think that the settings in the pool connection  in ( applicationContext-db.xml ) should be changed in order to use the best configuration related to the performance of the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too late an answer, but let's see how it goes (or went).

1. why is `maxConnectionAge` set to 10? It's too short. By the way, it's in seconds, not hours. What it means is that even if and when your connection is not idle, it can only live up to 10 seconds. That's mass killing of your application.
2. `maxIdleTime` could be increased from the current 180 seconds to say an hour or even higher. The point of using a connection pooling is to reduce the creation/destruction of underlying DB connections so frequently.
3. Though this is not related to the timeout issue you had, `maxStatements` could be increased as well. If your app is constantly polling a DB table for changes or updating it as and when new entries occur, this could come handy.

Checkout C3P0's [configuration documentaion](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuration) for more details.

Comment: your avatar picture looks garbled in the miniatures on my Ubuntu on both chrome and firefox (and probably other configurations): the lower half is missing. Thought you might appreciate the info and maybe do something about it (it's a pretty picture when complete :) ). I write here, because alas, there is no other way on SO. See https://pasteboard.co/HCKIbpG.png

Comment: @Rick77 yeah, I had seen it the first time I changed the pic a few years ago :-) Not sure if it's a gravatar problem or SO problem.

Comment: Ah, ok: I just wanted to inform you for your sake :) have a nice weekend